# "cannot find symbol" error in maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I see a lot of questions on stackoverflow on this. But still I'm not able to know what is the issue in my way of building projects.

I've two spring boot projects: we-data and we-web. we-web is dependent on we-data. we-data compiles fine on maven. But we-web gives me above error.

we-data pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.we</groupId>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>we-data</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

we-web pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.we</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>we-web</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.we</groupId>
            <artifactId>data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Everytime I do maven "clean compile package install" goals on we-web I get the maven error. All the symbols that this complains isn't found are all in we-data project. For some reason, it says all the classes of we-data cannot be found in we-web. But when I run the application as spring boot app, everything is fine. No maven error matters for this.:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building we-web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ web ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\we\we-web\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\we\we-web\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/we/we-web/src/main/java/com/we/controller/EmployeeController.java:[13,25] package com.we.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/we/we-web/src/main/java/com/we/controller/EmployeePaymentController.java:[22,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EmployeeService
  location: class com.we.controller.EmployeePaymentController
.
.
.
[INFO] 44 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.322 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-26T15:30:54+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/253M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
.
.
```

I have 1.8 jdk being used by the STS. And also I have not put the we-data project on build path for we-web. I want this to pass, because I want to generate a war of this. Please help. I'm doing "clean compile package install" on we-data and then doing it on we-web. "Update maven project" is also not helping me.

Comment: Looks like package mismatch - pls correct the import and resolve this `com.we.service does not exist`. Hope this should resolve the build

Comment: @ClementAmarnath: No, the packages' import are all right. If that was the case I shouldn't have got the we-web running. But it runs fine. I get the error only when I do maven build. I have the same kind of package structure in both the projects. Can that cause any problem? Updated the question.

Comment: In that case, try this delete your .m2 for `we-data`, build `we-data` and then `we-web`

Comment: Don't create 2 spring boot projects. You shouldn't be including a spring-boot project into another spring boot project. The jar isn't a normal jar so the resources cannot be found (although before 1.4 this worked you still shouldn't be doing it). Make we-data a regular jar and not a spring boot jar. If they both are standalone projects, then one shouldn't depend on the other in the first place.

Answer (score 38):

I've been stuck on this problem too for a day and finally found the root cause and solution here what i've done:

if you have the following lines on your pom (for your case is the **we-data's** pom)

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

you should remove those lines and change into:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

after got a clue from [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) i found that he's correct about the jar compiled won't be a normal jar if you using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, thanks for the clue anyway.

and also please check this question: [Dependency not found in Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446501/dependency-not-found-in-spring-boot-project)

I've tried to use this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

it works like a charm.

Comment: Worked for me.. Spring boot jar dependency was not working by default.

Comment: Adding the configuration classifier `exec` fixed it for me as well.  It outputs two separate jars on build: one normal one `app.jar` (same as you would get when building without this plugin) and a new one for the fat jar `app-exec.jar`.  From your explanation that the fat jar is not recognized as a normal jar, I'm guessing that the original one needs to be present to fix it. Cheers!

Comment: I put the configuration below <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>, and without <executions> tags. With your solution, it produces 3 jars, app-version.jar.original, app-version.jar, and app-version-exec.jar. Without <executions> tags, it produces two jars: app-version.jar and app-version-exec.jar.

Comment: What is the importance of putting `<id>repackage</id>` because it worked for me after putting this in execution tag.

Answer (score 4):

> Everytime I do maven "clean compile package install" goals on we-web I
>   get the maven error. All the symbols that this complains isn't found
>   are all in we-data project.

1) I think you should read the introduction about Maven pom [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) and [lifecycle in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

```
mvn clean compile package install
```

is redundant for compile and package phases since the install phase includes these phases (.
So, do this only :

```
mvn clean install
```

2) Your web module where you run the maven goal requires the `com.we:data:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` dependency with your actual code :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.we</groupId>
        <artifactId>data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you add or modify code and you don't install this module, the web module cannot see these changes.

So you should do  `mvn clean install` in the  `com.we:data` module before doing that in the web module.

Finally the simplest to avoid having non updated dependency is running `mvn clean install` from a [multi-module project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) which aggregates these modules.

Comment: I've been building we-data first and then building we-web. But now, I'm doing "mvn clean install" instead of "mvn clean compile package install"(Thanks for that). That's not working. I would like to go with creating multi-module project for this as you suggested. But I don't know how to create multi-module "spring boot" project(also spring boot maven module(pardon if I'm sounding stupid)). Let me know if you can help me on this or I should open a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You are welcome. "That's not working." Having a multi module project will not resolve the missing class at compile time.It allows only to have a more robust build as all is ordered. Can you detail your error, edit your post and show all relevant information (package with classes missing for example)?

Answer (score 1):

In my case in Spring Boot application I had the following service and accompanying non-public classes in a single `ServiceFoo.java` file:

```
@Service
public class ServiceFoo {
}
class Foo { }
class Bar { }
```

At some point Maven started to fail with `cannot find symbol: class Service`.

Only after moving classes Foo and Bar into separate java files (`Foo.java` and `Bar.java` respectively) the error disappeared. Looks like either Maven (3.5.2 and 3.6.3) or Java (1.8.0_201) bug.

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml, Add depedency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

and class where you are using @Inject Import javax.inject.Inject  `import javax.inject.Inject`;

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error "cannot find symbol" .

I got 2 maven modules front and back and the front module could not access to the back module despite the dependency.

The problem was on the pom.xml in the back module. I remove these lines :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

and I just got these lines in the front pom module.