# Dependency not found in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When doing a *mvn clean compile* in projectA I'm getting a **package does not exist** compilation error. The error is refering to a package imported from projectB, which is a Spring Boot project (projectA is a regular maven project). projectB compiles nicely and the resulting jar is in my local maven repo.

projectB is included in projectA:

```
    <projectB.version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</projectB.version>

    [...]

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
        <version>${projectB.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I already did the usual cleaning and also deleted the contents of the local repo for projectB manually.

Comment: Can you try deleting the directory of projectB in your local maven repository and doing a new clean install of B (and then A)?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 1.4? Does `projectB` uses the spring-boot repackage goal? If both of these questions are true -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not use the repackage goal, but after going from

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

to

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

...it worked.

Comment: i have same issue. after adding the plugin, i always have a compilation error. Please check my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364697/mvn-compilation-error-error-reading-jar-error-in-opening-zip-file

Comment: Hi, please mark this as true answer, I've tried your solutions and it worked!